# How can I create a new column and add matching values ​against matching rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I can find equal column data with the merge function. But there is something else I want to do.
For example; If the "customer ID" in the second file has values ​​equal to the customer ID in the first file; How can I add the "customer rating" values ​​of the matching "customer ID" in the "second_file_data" file to rows with matching values ​​in the new column to be created in the "first_file_data" file?

```
 df= pd.merge(first_file_data,second_file_data,left_on='CUSTOMER ID',right_on='CUSTOMER ID')
```

Output:

Similar customer IDs in the merge transaction:

FİRST FİLE

```
  CUSTOMER ID  CUSTOMER SCORE  CUSTOMER CODE
0  3091250      100                 x
1  1122522      50                  x
```

SECOND_FİLE

```
  CUSTOMER ID  CUSTOMER SCORE  CUSTOMER CODE
0  3091250      750              I84E524
1  1122522      890              T8Y4H5D
```

new table to be formed:
FİRST FİLE

```
  CUSTOMER ID  CUSTOMER SCORE  CUSTOMER CODE
0  3091250      100              I84E524
1  1122522      50               2TWEYU5
```

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  Can you add a third data frame showing the output you want?

Comment: I am so sorry I had the wrong table. I fixed it now. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the customer id to as the index, then use update to fill in any null values.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('CUSTOMER ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('CUSTOMER ID')

df1.update(df2[['CUSTOMER CODE']], overwrite=True)

df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: If the places are full, what should I do? Is there a way to do this? Because usually those cells are always full in the files I receive. very thank you